# Check that $\lim\limits_{n \to\infty} (1-p_n + tp_n)^n = \lim\limits_{n \to\infty} (1-\lambda/n + t \lambda/n)^n $, or not

Tags: limits, exponential-function

Assume that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} np_n = \lambda$ with $\lambda > 0$. Am I allowed to assume that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1-p_n + tp_n)^n = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1-\lambda/n + t \lambda/n)^n = e^{-\lambda(1-t)} $ for $t \in \Bbb R$? If I am not allowed to assume it directly, how could I come from the left side of the equation to the right side?

Comment: How can the limit of $p_n$ as $n\to +\infty$ be something that depends on $n$?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: You wrote that $\lim_n p_n = \lambda/n$. This can not be true: the RHS should not depend on $n$, it makes no logical sense.

Comment: At most, you can say $\lim_n p_n = \lim_n \lambda/n$.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I treated $n$ as a constant here. This cannot be true of course.

Comment: You have that $p_n \sim \lambda /n$ as $n\to \infty$. Then you can effectively swap $p_n$ and $\lambda/n$ to get that second limit equality as the $n$th power is a continuous function.

Comment: What do you mean by $p_n$ ~ $\lambda/n$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68965/discussion-between-g-s-and-borol).

Answer (score 2):

In full generality, one cannot deduce that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}F(n,p_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}F(n,\lambda/n)$$ simply from the hypothesis that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}np_n=\lambda$$ But in the present case, $$F(n,p)=(1-sp)^n$$ with $s=1-t$ fixed, hence $$\log F(n,p)=n\log(1-sp)$$ Thus, if $p_n\to0$, then $$\log F(n,p_n)\sim-snp_n$$ *in the very precise sense that* $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log F(n,p_n)}{np_n}=-s$$ Assuming furthermore that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}np_n=\lambda$$ one gets $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\log F(n,p_n)=-s\lambda$$ hence $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-sp_n)^n=e^{-s\lambda}$$ The same reasoning applies when $p_n=\lambda/n$ hence indeed, all this shows that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-sp_n)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-s\lambda/n)^n$$ This identity does not follow from a general principle but merely as a byproduct of the fact, that we showed above, that both sequences have limit $e^{-s\lambda}$.

Comment: Don't see why you are downvoted right now. I rewrote the question such that your answer can be applied directly to it.

Comment: "Don't see why you are downvoted right now" Please do not worry about this. Such unfortunate events are common on the site, the list of usual suspects goes from users unhappy that their answer, here or elsewhere, was proven rubbish, to any other character happy to have been given the right to downvote and/or unable to understand the answer and/or whatnot. Again, no big deal.